# How to change a slug and remove the last part of URL in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect some old URLs to a new ones. In this case I have to change the first part of the path and remove the last one, but no matter what I try the RewriteRule doesn't seem to apply.

I need this URL 
`https://siteurl.com/prodotto/sport/baseball/bsb01` 
to be 
`https://siteurl.com/prodotti/sport/baseball`

I've tried everything I could but nothing happens. I'm getting crazy already.

This is the last rule I've tried

`RewriteRule ^.?prodotto\/(.*)\/([\s\S]*)$ /prodotti/$2 [R=301,L]`

The pattern seems to be right (https://regex101.com/r/445pP2/1) but on my website it doesn't work.

Note: The mod_rewrite works because I have other redirects that works.

This is the full htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

# Bearer token
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
# End bearer token

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

# ...other settings...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^societa.volleysport.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^atleti.volleysport.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^entiescuole.volleysport.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nets.volleysport.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^balls.volleysport.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^protezioni.volleysport.it$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://volleysport.it%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^.?prodotto/(.*)/([\s\S]*)$ /prodotti/$1 [R=301,L]

# this is for the category links, to replace /categoria/ with /prodotti/
Redirect 301 /categoria/ /prodotti/
```

Comment: Your first capture group catches `sport/baseball`, the second one `bsb01` - so you should be appending $1 and not $2, no?

Comment: True, thanks, but that's not the point. The point is it really doesn't work. The rule gets ignored. The actual link is this http://stage.volleysport.it/prodotto/sport/slackline/sl181 and should be http://stage.volleysport.it/prodotti/sport/slackline

Comment: Show your full rewriting configuration then, please.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question with the full .htaccess content

Comment: Try and put that rule closer to the beginning of the .htaccess. Presumably here `RewriteRule . index.php` has already rewritten the request internally because it doesn’t match anything physically existing, and therefor it won’t match `^.?prodotto/…` later on any more. (General rule-of-thumb when it comes to rewriting - order stuff from most specific, to least.)

Comment: A.W.E.S.O.M.E.! Thank you very very much. It works! I guess I missed the rule "most specific to least".